# Failed building wheel for pyarrow in pypy3 interpreter

Tags: python, streamlit, pyarrow, pypy

I am installing streamlit with pypy3 as interpreter in pycharm and stuck at this `ERROR: Failed building wheel for pyarrow`
I tried every solutions found on the web related with pyarrow, but seems like all solutions posted are for python as interpreter and not for pypy. If you guys have any solution, please let me know.

Command : `pip install streamlit`
Operating system : `ubuntu 22.04`
pypy3 version : `7.3.9`

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "/home/lungsang/Desktop/streamlit/.env/bin/cmake", line 5, in <module>
          from cmake import cmake
      ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cmake'
      error: command '/home/lungsang/Desktop/streamlit/.env/bin/cmake' failed with exit code 1
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for pyarrow
Failed to build pyarrow
ERROR: Could not build wheels for pyarrow, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

I have installed cmake before running the command.

Comment: can you please provide more information. What command is it exactly you are running? what is the full error message / stack trace? What version of pypy3 are you using and which operating system? Thanks.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like currently pyarrow can't be use with pypy.

https://github.com/apache/arrow/issues/2089

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You need to `pypy3 -m pip install cmake`. With that, I am not sure this will work. Even if it does, pyarrow is a c++-based project, so the PyPy python JIT will have a hard time finding opportunities to speed up python code. Additionally, the need to emulate the CPython interactions between python and C mean the code may actually run slower under PyPy than under CPython, if you can get it to run at all.